# Android Google Map Pins display with different sizes on different phones

Tags: android, google-maps-markers, google-maps-android-api-2, android-drawable

I am trying try implement display of pins on Android Google Maps.

I've successfully implemented it. However I'm abit confused as to why the pins are displayed in different sizes on different phones.

I am currently using the same R.drawable png file, which is stored under /res/drawable folder. Why is this happening? Is there a way to standardize this?

Below is a comparison for example, between a Samsung and HTC phone:

[image]

Comment: Please make drawable folder under res folder.. then keep all the pin images in that .. then it wont get visible various sizes.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

- small screen phones -> 36 x 36 px (ldpi)(120dpi)image size(keep
  under res/drawable-ldpi folder)
- normal screen phones-> 48 x 48 px (mdpi)(160dpi)image size(under res/drawable-mdpi)
- large screen phones/tablets-> 72 x 72 px (hdpi)(240dpi)image size(under res/drawable-hdpi)
- extra screen tablets-> 96 x 96 px (xhdpi)(320dpi)image size(under res/drawable-xhdpi)

if you have 4 PNG files with above mentioned size in appropriate folders, then it should look fine on all phones/tablets.

Comment: you can use android asset studio to create those PNG files.

Comment: Oh so I can't just put it in the res/drawable folder, but instead have to create the different sizes and put them in those separate folders? Then what is the res/drawable folder for then?

Comment: Yes. that is how your application can support different screen size and resolutions. you might also need to have separate layouts too.

Comment: Not sure if it does but I don't have the different sizes so I'm trying to do them up now and see if it works...!

Comment: google android asset studio and use it to create those PNG files.

Comment: how to select svg??

Answer (score 0):

Please make drawable folder under res folder.. then keep all the pin images in that .. then it wont get visible various sizes.

Answer (score 0):

I'm having trouble with map marker sizes too. I put them in the drawable folder but then lint
started complaining and told me:

```
  ... "If the icon really is density independent (for example a solid color) 
  you can place it in drawable-nodpi."
```

I did that. The markers look more consistent across a 7" and a 9" screen and lint is happy too.  I'm using Android map V2.

Answer (score 0):

Please make drawable folder under res folder.. then keep all the pin images in that .. then delete all other drawable folder like drawable-mdpi,drawable-hdpi etc...only keep drawable folder and store image in that folder.